# Comparing Methods For Solving Double Integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, definite-integrals

For my assignment I'm asked to compute a given double integral using these methods:

```
Composite Simpson's Rule: 4.08
Composite Trapezoidal Rule: 4.37
Non-Rectangular Region: 3.57
Gaussian Quadrature: 4.11
```

and I need to compare these methods, comment on their usefulness. So, what I did was I computed the actual value of the given double integral(using http://www.wolframalpha.com),
then I compared which one is the closest to the actual result. Are there other ways on comparing and knowing the usefulness of the methods? I think I need to learn more about the methods, but it's sort of difficult. I just substitute values into the formula for each methods.